# consulta ao banco com ajax no beforeSend

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

Como fazer uma consulta ao banco com `ajax` no `beforeSend`?

Exemplo:

```
    var formData = new FormData(this); 

    $.ajax({
        url: "../_requeridos/cadastraPlano.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function() {               
        },
        success: function (retorno) {...
```

Gostaria de saber se já existe o cadastro no banco antes de cadastrar.

Alguma coisa como:

```
beforeSend: function() {               
   acessa consultaRegistro.php
  // pesquisa aqui e se o registro já houver alerta o navegador!
  //Nesse caso, não chega a entrar no success. Ou seja, não faz a inserção no banco.
        },
```

Como fazer isso?

Veja como está o arquivo do insert:

```
<?php
    require_once "../_controles/_conexao/Conexao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_util/PhpUtil.php";     
    require_once "../_controles/_util/Constantes.php";      
    require_once "../_controles/_models/Planos.php";    
    require_once "../_controles/_models/Fotos.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_models/Upload.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/PlanosDao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/FotosDao.php";
    require_once "../_controles/_daos/UploadDao.php";

    $connection = new Conexao(); 
    $conexao = $connection->abreConexao();
    $phpUtil = new PhpUtil(); 
    $constantes = new Constantes($phpUtil); 
    $planosDao = new PlanosDao($conexao);
    $fotosDao = new FotosDao($conexao);

    $nomePlano = $_POST["nomePlano"];   
    $descricao = $_POST["descricao"];   

    $plano = new Planos(                 
                     $nomePlano,
                     $descricao);

    $pesquisaPlano = $planosDao->pesquisaPlanos("WHERE nome = '".$nomePlano."'");   

    if($pesquisaPlano == NULL) {

        $cadastraPlano = $planosDao->cadastrar($plano);
        $ultimoId = $planosDao->ultimoIdCadastrado();
        require_once "upload.php";

    }   else $cadastraPlano = 3;        

    echo $cadastraPlano

?>
```

Comment: Amigo você fará essa verificação no back-end, quando sua requisição chegar no php você faz uma consulta e verifica se já existe.

Comment: quer dizer no próprio arquivo de inserção? Isto é: antes da inserção

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, porque mesmo que você consiga fazer no beforeSend() você terá de fazer uma requisição pra saber se o registro existe.

Comment: Pois é, é exatamente isso que eu queria, Fazer essa verificação no before e se o registro existir, não chegar a enviar o formulário

Comment: Desse modo seria 2 requisições no back-end, e quanto menos requisições melhor, você pode fazer tudo no scopo da mesma requisição.

Comment: como ficaria? Pode dar um exemplo? Eu editei a pergunta e coloquei o arquivo de inserção no final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  //Não faz o insert
}
} else {
  //Faz o insert
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado amigo.

Comment: Mas dessa forma, fica do jeito que eu postei na pergunta. Ou seja, uma nova consulta (insert) será feita do mesmo jeito! Mas valeu pela orientação nesse feriadão!

Comment: Se você fizesse no beforeSend() ele teria de fazer uma requisição pra saber se existe e com o retorno ele daria continuidade no resto do scopo do ajax e faria uma nova requisição só pra inserir o dado no banco. Desse modelo ele faz a verificação em apenas uma requisição.

Comment: Ahh entendi. Uma nova requisição ajax e não SQL. Ok. Agora ficou claro! Acha que pode me ajudar nessa outra questão? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303364/plugin-criando-espa%C3%A7o-vazio-abaixo-do-html-quando-redimensiona-a-tela

Comment: Dei uma olhada nessa outra questão, infelizmente não consegui te ajudar amigo.

Comment: ok, obrigado mesmo assim!